# Area of a semicircle minus a segment

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

How can you find the area of a semicircle minus a segment?

> [image]

Comment: Do you happen to be familiar with calculus?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Hint: break the area in question into two sectors and a triangle as shown. Since the area is symmetrical, it's sufficient to find one half of it. The angle of the green sector will be: $\frac{\pi}{2}-\arccos \frac{b}{a}$
Can you finish?

Comment: Hi. Got it now. Really appreciate it.

Comment: @davidcallahan: You are welcome!

Comment: @davidcallahan you probably mean $\arccos(b/a)$?

Comment: @psl2Z: Yes, thanks for noticing!

Answer (score 1):

With integration: Define $M = \{x^2+y^2\leq a^2\} \cap \{0\leq x\leq b\}$. Then: $|M| = 2\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\int_{0}^{\min(\frac{b}{\cos(\theta)},a)}rdrd\theta = \int_{0}^{\arccos(b/a)}\frac{b^2}{\cos(\theta)^2}d\theta + \int_{\arccos(b/a)}^{\pi/2}a^2d\theta = b^2 \tan(\arccos(b/a))+a^2(\pi/2-\arccos(b/a)) = b\sqrt{a^2-b^2} + a^2(\pi/2-\arccos(b/a))$